# VirtualBox, Remote Desktop, and VPN

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vpn, remote-desktop

Networking is not a strong skill set of mine and I'm new to VirtualBox..so here we go -

I've got a Windows (XP) VM running on VirtualBox. I am able to use remote desktop to connect to the VM with no problems.

The Problem: I need to connect to another network via VPN on the virtual machine. However, once connected, all local network resources become unavailable. As a result, my remote desktop session is disconnected.

Question: Is there another way to remotely access the VM? Is there some way that VirtualBox can route me to the VM without using the Windows RDC functionality so that I can have an active VPN connection but still control the VM remotely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should have done some more research. This feature is already built into VirtualBox. You can log into the VM through the host machine.

All you have to do is turn on remote display in the settings for the VM and choose the port that you want to use (make sure to make appropriate firewall changes). Then you remote to that port on the host machine.

Ex: Host machine has an IP of 192.168.1.200 and you set up port 3395 for the remote display - you would open Remote Desktop Connection and use 192.168.1.200:3395 and it would open the VM.

More detail from the VirtualBox site.
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html